# Copy and paste some lines for a sheet to a different one in the same Excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I've written the following to copy and paste some lines for a sheet to a different one in the same Excel file

```vb
Sub InsertDataButton()
    Dim wsbase As Worksheet, wsETL As Worksheet
    Set  wsbase = ThisWorkBook.Sheets("Values Data")
    set wsETL = ThisWorkBook.Sheets("ETL test")

    Dim sourceData As Variant
    Dim destinationRange As Range

    sourceData = Array(wsBase.Range("N8").Value, wsBase.Range("E8").Value, _
                       wsBase.Range("H8").Value, wsBase.Range("I8").Value, _
                       wsBase.Range("O8").Value)

    ' Set the destination range in Sheet2
    Set destinationRange = wsETL.Range("A2") ' Change the starting cell for destination

    ' Write data as text into respective columns in destination sheet
    destinationRange.Offset(0, 0).Value = sourceData(0) ' N8 into column A starting with cell A2
    destinationRange.Offset(0, 3).Value = sourceData(1) ' E8 into column D starting with cell D2
    destinationRange.Offset(0, 4).Value = sourceData(2) ' H8 into column E starting with cell E2
    destinationRange.Offset(0, 5).Value = sourceData(3) ' I8 into column F starting with cell F2
    destinationRange.Offset(0, 6).Value = sourceData(4) ' O8 into column G starting with cell G2
End Sub
```

I created a button (From Control) and added the path from assign macro.

When I run the macro from the VBA, no errors but I don't get any output, same with the button.
Meaning no errors but it doesn't pull data from sheet Base to sheet ETL.

I tried creating a new button to assign the existing macro (module) but I get the same results.

I tried to edit my code but the code provided by VBasic2008 looked much better.

Currently the code I'm using

```vb
Sub InsertDataButton()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Values Data")
    Dim sRow As Long: sRow = 8
    Dim sLast As Long: sLast = 2000 ' Change value for wanted last row
    
    Dim sCols() As Variant: sCols = Array("N", "E", "H", "I", "O")
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("ETL Test")
    Dim dRow As Long: dRow = 2
    Dim dCols() As Variant: dCols = Array("A", "D", "E", "F", "G")
    
    Dim scell As Range, dcell As Range, c As Long, r As Long
    Dim lookupValue As Variant
    Dim hValue As Variant
    
    ' Get the lookup value from "Contracts" sheet cell $D$14
    lookupValue = wb.Sheets("Contracts").Range("D14").Value
    
    ' Copy values and lookup
    For r = sRow To sLast
        For Each scell In sws.Range("H" & r) ' Check each cell in column H
            hValue = scell.Value
            ' Check if H has value if not skip
            If IsNumeric(hValue) And hValue <> 0 Then
                For c = LBound(sCols) To UBound(sCols)
                    Set scell = sws.Cells(r, sCols(c))
                    Set dcell = dws.Cells(dRow + r - sRow, dCols(c))
                    dcell.Value = scell.Value
                Next c
                
                ' Set value 12 in column B for each row copied
                dws.Cells(dRow + r - sRow, "B").Value = 12
                
                ' do XLOOKUP in column C from "Liste Date"
                dws.Cells(dRow + r - sRow, "C").Formula = "=XLOOKUP(" & Chr(34) & lookupValue & Chr(34) & ", 'Liste Date'!P:P, 'Liste Date'!Q:Q)"
                
                Exit For 
            End If
        Next scell
    Next r
    
    MsgBox "Values copied.", vbInformation 
End Sub
```

Although it looks through each value and only copies the values which have a non 0 number into the column H, it still maintains the rows from which copies the data.

Example: Copies data from values sheet line 4 to ETL line 4 but if line 5 is empty so does the values sheet remain.
[image]

How do I clear the empty lines?

Comment: Add `MsgBox Join(sourceData, vbLf)` before `Set destinationRange ..` to check the values in the array.

Comment: You mention "some lines" and "starting with cell A2" as if you're trying to do this for multiple rows, are you not seeing a difference from when you tested the code from VBA (makes sense as these are hard-coded ranges) or is there actually nothing done? You can also use `Debug.Print "Got in"` to see if you got into the sub or use F9 (while in your code) to insert a breakpoint.

Comment: I've added the MsgBox and now when I'm running my code it returns :
Run-time error : "`13"
Type mismatch 
could this be due to the fact that in Column N,H I have numbers while in the others letters ? 
Should I in this case add one more line to specify that everything should be converted to string characters ?

Comment: The code works fine. Check if there is data in the cells of the source worksheet. Also, `ThisWorkbook` means the workbook containing this code. If it's another one, you have to reference it differently (e.g. `Workbooks("Test.xlsx")` or `ActiveWorkbook`).

Comment: So I did take the provided code and paste it into my  excel but after running it, I'm only seeing the popup box message saying the Values copied but they are not actually copied. I'm working with only one Excel document which has both sheets in it. Yes the cells from which I want to pull the data contain information

Comment: "they are not actually copied" - how are you checking this ? amend the first  write to `destinationRange.Offset(0, 0).Value = "sourceData(0)"`

Comment: It was a mistake in my part, Yea the code was working correctly. I did erase the lines below line 8 in order to see if the code will copy everything below line 8 and that's why I was saying it won't copy anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Copy Values From One Discontinuous Range to Another

[image]

```vb
Sub InsertDataButton()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Values Data")
    Dim sRow As Long: sRow = 8
    Dim sCols() As Variant: sCols = Array("N", "E", "H", "I", "O")
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("ETL Test")
    Dim dRow As Long: dRow = 2
    Dim dCols() As Variant: dCols = Array("A", "D", "E", "F", "G")
    
    Dim scell As Range, dcell As Range, c As Long
    
    ' Copy values.
    For c = LBound(sCols) To UBound(sCols)
        Set scell = sws.Cells(sRow, sCols(c))
        Set dcell = dws.Cells(dRow, dCols(c))
        dcell.Value = scell.Value
        'Debug.Print dcell.Address(0, 0), scell.Address(0, 0)
        ' or simply:
        'dws.Cells(dRow, dCols(c)).Value = sws.Cells(sRow, sCols(c)).Value
    Next c
    
    MsgBox "Values copied.", vbInformation

End Sub
```